# Delegate method not being called in skscene

Tags: ios

I have a game that launches right into the skscene and the main menu is set up in the skscene. there is a button you can click to segue to a different view controller with a page to select a new character. I set up a protocol in this view controller called storedelegate to alert the skscene that the character has been changed so that it can switch out the character images.

This is my .h file for the character selection view controller

```
 @protocol StoreDelegate <NSObject>

@required
-(void)didSelectCharachter;

@end

@interface StoreViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<StoreDelegate> storeDelegate;
@end`
```

`this is my .m file where i call the delegate method when the buy button is clicked

```
-(void)didTouchUpInsideBuyBuyyon {
    NSString *newCharachter = [self selectCharachterWithIndex:self.charachterCounter];
    [[UserManager sharedInstace] setPlayersCharachterWithCurrentCharachter:newCharachter];
    [self.storeDelegate didSelectCharachter];
}
```

Here is the .m file of my skscene where i implement the store delegate and then implement a method. I have put a break point on this method and it is never called.

```
@interface MyScene ()<SKPhysicsContactDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate, StoreDelegate>

#pragma mark - StoreDelegate

-(void)didSelectCharachter {
    NSLog(@"newCharachterWasSelected");
}
```

Comment: in MyScene when add StoreViewController did you assign storeViewController.storeDelegate = self ?

Comment: im not sure what you mean. I just tried adding this into the init method of MyScene: StoreViewController *vc = [[StoreViewController alloc] init];
        vc.storeDelegate = self; and this still didn't work